# include multiple column value in Ruby on rails Collection_select. Also format the date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Earlier i was using This code

```
<%= select "selected_payment", "id", @shifts.map {|u| [' ' +u.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") + '-' + u.end_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")+' ',u.id]} %>   to make a dropdown.
```

Now i have to do same thing with collection_select. But i'm not able to figure how to do it.
It will be something like the one given below :

```
<%= f.collection_select :shift_id, @shifts,:id, :start_time, :prompt => true %>
```

I can not even format the date and use two values at the same time.
Please help,Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002297) In your model for ex:- `Shift`

```
def start_end_time
 ' ' +self.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") + '-' + self.end_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")+' '
end
```

In views

```
<%= f.collection_select :shift_id, @shifts,:id, :start_end_time, :prompt => true %>
```

Answer (score 2):

i found myself with the same question and i solve it doing this...

at my user.rb

```
  def first_and_last_name    
    "#{self.first_name} " " #{self.last_name}"   
  end
```

at my view

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :first_and_last_name, {}, class: 'ui search dropdown' ) %>
```